# How do I create e-products, and store order id+uid in my own tables in case of successful purchase via PayPal

Tags: users, 6, ubercart, payment-gateways

On a website I'm developing, there's a plan that **users could buy some "online" products (or e-products) cheaply via PayPal, and than give these products to each other as a present.**
For example, one user could buy a star (or more) for 1€, and send this star to another user he/she likes as a gift.
So nothing would be shipped, nothing would be downloaded.
I already have Ubercart set up with a PayPal Sandbox API key (there will be other products too), so I can see that online transactions seem to work successfully for products that can be shipped.

1. **How can I create products that can not be shipped, can not be downloaded, just simply purchased and registered, assigned to a given user (like an "online" product, which users can utilize on an online surface)?**
   I could create a "star" product in my Ubercart webshop, let users buy it, and than check this type's stuffs in Ubercart tables.
2. **After a successful purchase, how could I check the order id (for the "star" product), and store the purchase process in my own tables** to let users present these "online" products to each other (there would also be a field to whom it was sent) and register when this whole thing happened, and that one user already took this opportunity?
   (To let you understand why it's needed: there would also be a little icon on the site indicating that users already have e.g. 12 stars that could be virtually given to another user; besides, there would be another icon indicating the user got a star from another user [which user gave it, and when]. I would also like to generate an own unique code for these stars to utilize them later for example for a draw!)

Any good ideas are appreciated. Ask if anything isn't quite clear!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, solved it with Conditional Actions!

1. I created a new product class on `/admin/store/products/classes` site. Let's call it "`My Stuff`" (class id: `my_stuff`).
2. The previous step created a new content type with the "`My Stuff`" name. So I went to "**Create content** > My Stuff" (`/node/add/my-stuff`).
3. I left *"Product and its derivatives are shippable."* **UNCHECKED** (as I didn't to be shipped). **Gave it an own SKU**, sell price, description, uploaded an image, etc. as usual. OK, product created.
4. Went to "**Conditional actions**" (`/admin/store/ca` ; don't forget to enable this module), "**Add a predicate**" (`/admin/store/ca/add`).
5. Gave it a title, set "**Customer completes checkout**" trigger, gave a description, set my own class, set status to Enabled, pushed "*Save predicate*" button.
6. Under "Conditions" tab, selected "**Check an order's products**", pushed "*Add condition*" button.
7. Under "**Product models:**", I selected the SKU given in step 3.
8. Clicked on "**Actions**" tab. Selected "**Execute custom PHP code**", pushed "*Add action*" button.
9. Here I could "play" with the **`$order` and `$account` variables** in my custom code, and this was the key. This way I could loop through `$order->products` array (with `for` or `foreach`), reach the customer's user id via `$order->uid` (or `$account->uid`), read quantities (in the loop, with e.g. `$order->products[$product_index]->qty`, where `$product_index` is the actual index of the loop steps) and save them in my own database tables with `db_query()` function. Everything needed could now be saved in my own tables where they could be handled the appropriate way, so everything works fine now. I'm happy. [image: cool]